# XNA 3D Camera & Billboard Camera Facing Rotation

Tags: xna

Please can you help me with the following questions?

1. How do I **rotate** (about the Z axis) a **camera position** around a Vector3 as pivot?
2. How do I **rotate** (about the Z axis) a **quad object** positioned in front of that camera and make sure that the **quad always faces the camera** around the same Vector3 pivot?

The picture to explain it is below:

[image: Image showing the concept of a billboard]

Please kindly answer, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to rotating the camera around that vector3 point, you can also use that as the target that the camera is looking at. Then you only need to transform the camera's position around that point. It appears that the up vector for making the camera will always stay the same. You mention the Z axis but XNA is a Y-up system so from your image you would perform rotations about the Y axis.

```
Vector3 pivotPoint = new Vector3(?, ?, ?);
cameraPosition = Vector3.Transform(cameraPosition - pivotPoint, Matrix.CreateRotationY(anglePerFrame)) + pivotPoint;
View = Matrix.CreatLookAt(cameraPosition, pivotPoint, Vector3.Up);

Matrix billboardWorld = Matrix.Identity;
billBoardWorld.Forward = Vector3.Normalize(cameraPosition - pivotPoint);
billboardWorld.Right = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(billboardWorld.Forward, Vector3.Up));
billboardWorld.Translation = cameraPosition - (billboardWorld.Backwards * distFromCamera);
```

Comment: Ok great it FIX the camera rotation, thanks

But about the facing still problem, first of all I'm using Vector3.Zero as pivot, second I dunno what is distfromcamera mean? is it distance of each quad origin vector3 to the camera or what? I'm trying this:

Comment: Matrix billboardWorld = Matrix.Identity;
                billboardWorld.Forward = Vector3.Normalize(camPosition - Vector3.Zero);
                billboardWorld.Right = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(billboardWorld.Forward, Vector3.Up));
                billboardWorld.Translation = camPosition - (billboardWorld.Backward * (Vector3.Distance(camPosition, quad.Origin)));
                quad.World = billboardWorld;

quad does rotate problem is first the quad does not exists then suddenly as camera rotating counter clockwise, the quad appear from right moving left racing the camera then dissapear?

Comment: 'distanceFromCamera' means the distance (in xna units) that you want the billboard to be from the camera... how far away from the camera the billboard is.

Comment: Try billboardWorld.Translation = cameraPosition + (billboardWorld.Backwards * distFromCamera); //for the last line of the snippet I placed. I think I placed a - (minus) when I should have placed a + (plus).

Comment: (Note for future readers): in @user733916's code snippet in their comment just above, they attempt to dynamically compute distFromCamera - a formula that is mixing the camera's dynamic position with the quad's origin: `Vector3.Distance(camPosition, quad.Origin)`. This would not make any sense; "distFromCamera" should be a value that you feed in to the formula. So if you want a constant distance from camera, you supply that constant distance:  `distFromCamera = 15.0;`

Comment: NOTE: This answer does exactly what OP's diagram shows - a billboard *moving with the camera*. This would act as a HUD element - would maintain an apparently fixed position on the screen. [Use this if it is easier in your situation than overlaying 2D HUD.] For what most people want when asking about billboards, which is a billboard that stays in one position *in the world*, but rotates to face camera (think "tree"), use the last line from [James answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12452509/199364), in place of the last line here.  Or use James answer in its entirety, instead of this.

Answer (score 2):

Note that XNA has a helper for this Matrix.CreateBillboard(...), although if you have access to the camera matrix it is probably simpler to do the following:

```
        var billboardWorld = Matrix.Invert(camera.ViewMatrix);
        billboardWorld.Translation = billboardPosition;
```

Comment: Comparing this to accepted answer, it shows a simpler way to *orient* the billboard. The `Matrix.Invert` line is equivalent to the first three lines of the `billboard` section of Steve H's code. Then you can use Steve's final line to compute the value to put in "billboardPosition", *if* you want the billboard to *move* with the camera, as it appears to do in OP's diagram. However, that is **not** what is usually wanted for billboards  If instead, you want the billboard to **stay where it is in the world**; to maintain a **constant position**, then James answer is showing how to do so.

Comment: If I am not mistaken this is not "true" billboarding, you are just aligning object with the plane of the camera. Which works perfectly with quads, but not so good with 3D objects, so it should be worth to mention this is more billboarding "hack" for specific use case.